# Fail to access Modx Manager from a different computer. Says password and username are incorrect

Tags: content-management-system, xampp, localhost, modx

I am new to Modx. I successfully installed and set up Modx on my laptop on localhost using xampp. However I would like to work on Modx on my desktop. I have copied over the htdocs onto my desktop. And have set up my database identically. When accessing Modx Manager, my username and password is said to be incorrect. I am using the same username and password and it works on my laptop (I have checked for typos). I do not understand why I am unable to log in. Can someone guide me so I can successfully work on my Modx on my desktop computer?

Comment: Create new user with full access and new password and try once again.

Comment: Just created a new user with full access. I am still unable to log in on my desktop.

Comment: Try another browser?

Answer (score 0):

Often a stale session from your browser can prevent login. Try logging in from an incognito window.

Also, did you ensure that the MODX install on your desktop has the correct paths in config.core.php files? There's one in your document root, one in your manager folder, and one in your connectors folder.

Furthermore the paths and DB connection info need to be environment specific, in {core_path}/config/{config_key}.inc.php
When you migrated the site to your desktop, did you run the setup program again? Often that helps to fix paths, but you need to normalize the config.inc.php file first.

If you can access the database directly, you can change the hash_class value for your user in the modx_users table to hashing.modMD5 *temporarily* so that you can manually enter an MD5-hashed password. Maybe there's an issue with the PBKDF2 on your desktop local environment.

Some ideas to try, anyways.